# command output is directed to the screen

Tags: perl

novice Perl programmer here!.
I'm using the system() function to get the return code for an external program (in this case - php), however, the command's output is still printed to the screen.
How do I prevent it from doing so?
My code is:

```
use strict; use warnings;
print 'Return code:', system('php -l wrong.php'), "\n";
```

This code does print the return code, but it also print the the output of the command executed.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: further testing shown that this happens while only using the php lint command.. using it with other commands doesnt print anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a UNIX-like OS, you should be able to redirect the output in the command:

Try:
`system('php -l wrong.php >> /dev/null')` to get rid of what's being sent to stdout.

You could also [open the command with a pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens) to handle the output directly, which should be more portable.

Comment: the idea about shell redirects was right but the syntax was wrong (php was writing to STDERR & to the STDOUT). the command was supposed to be: `php -l wrong.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html):

```
    use IPC::Open3;
    use Symbol qw(gensym);

    my $err = gensym; #work around IPC::Open3's interface
    my $pid = open3 my $wtr, my $rdr, $err,
            'some cmd', 'arg1', 'arg2', ...;
```

The separates out stdin into `$wtr`, stdout into `$rdr`, and stderr into `$err`
This also gives you maximum control over communicating with the process

Comment: It's supposed to go into a small utility script, does all that code is neccesery? is there no other way?

Comment: GZaidman: I suspect this answer is because you said what you didn't want (output going to the screen) but didn't say what you did want (output thrown away), leading to a guess that you wanted the output captured.